# Can I use MassTransit/Automatonymous saga without using entire MassTransit framework?

Tags: c#, .net, masstransit, saga, automatonymous

I am looking for best .Net Saga framework. Automatonymous looks promising, but all samples and docs are related to it's parent MassTransit project.

Is it possible to use Automatonymous based saga without MassTransit itself? If yes - *how would you persist saga state* and *how would you rehydrate saga state* when new messages arrives? I can't find anything regarding this topic despite 3 days of search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatonymous is (well, was, but still is) a standalone project. But it has seen limited adoption outside of MassTransit for the reasons you state: instance management, loading and saving instances, identity, etc.

Which is why with v8 of MassTransit, the Automatonymous codebase has been fully integrated to provide a seamless developer experience. Concerns such as instance/state management are handled by the saga repository, which is message-based. I haven't thought about providing any other affordances to dispatch events to state machines outside of the saga repository at this point.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I read MassTransit/Automatonymous docs pretty thoroughly, however I miss where exactly sagas' state are persisted, and where exactly they are rehydrated. Do you mind pointing me (or updating docs) with this piece of information?

Comment: The [documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/sagas/persistence.html) covers the various saga storage engines.